# How to get a full list of Steam games ONLY (no DLCs, no trailers,...etc.) using Steam Web API

Tags: steam, webapi

Unfortunately I'm not able get a list of all steam games without DLCs and other stuff.

I can get a list of everything on steam with these links:

Older?: http or https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/

Newer?: http or https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/

A list of interfaces and methods tied to my key can be found here:

[http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v0001/?key={myKey}](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v0001/?key=%7BmyKey%7D)

Please notice "v0001" in the link. Not working with "v2"

There is an interface called "IStoreService" with the method "GetAppList" and the parameter "include_dlc", so I tried this:

[http://api.steampowered.com/IStoreService/GetAppList/v0001/?key={myKey}&include_dlc=false](http://api.steampowered.com/IStoreService/GetAppList/v0001/?key=%7BmyKey%7D&include_dlc=false)

This loads a pretty old list ("newer" games like F1 2017-2020 are not included) and leaving out the dlc parameter shows the same list.

I tried a couple of different variations, but none is working.

Any help on this, please?

Best regards

Comment: Jim Grimett is the closest an answer can be. This will not be 100% possible though because not everything is properly marked by devs/pubs. Some demos are marked as games, and there may even be DLC and soundtracks improperly marked. Lol.

Comment: @TheFriesel , were you able to find any good alternative to the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The [SteamDB website](https://steamapi.xpaw.me/) has the best documentation for the various Steam APIs that I have found.

If you search for IStoreService you'll see that the GetAppList call will return up to 10,000 results by default. You can either increase this to 50,000 - which still won't be enough for the whole catalogue - or use the `last_appid` parameter to get pages of data.

HTH